# How to calculate Hamming distance in matlab for two vectors?

Tags: octave, hamming-distance

I need  to calculate the hamming distance between two vectors in octave. Searching in the internet, I found that Hamming distance by just using this function: pdist (), But it doesn't give me any result, because pdist() is a missing function in octave.

```
w= pdist([208    15   217   252   128    35    50   252   209   120    97   140   235   220    32   251],
       [231   174   143    43   125    66    49   143    48   139    81   103   154   229    93   229],1)
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me please.

Comment: Have you tried coding it yourself?

Comment: In fact no, I Think that pdist could be used referenced to this forum https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/159216-how-to-calculate-hamming-distance-between-vectors-in-matrix

Comment: pdist is part of the octave-forge statistics package

Comment: I found this answer too https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/89912-hamming-distance-between-two-binary-matrices

Comment: Unfortunately, `'hamming'` is not implemented for `pdist2` in Octave. Have you loaded the statistics package as @Andy suggested?

Comment: and btw, the hamming distance is just the count of symbls which aren't equal so it boild down to something like `sum (a != b)`

Comment: @Andy, yes it is easy I am trying to implement it, I will post my try

Answer (score 1):

- Hamming distance is a metric for comparing two binary data strings.
- While comparing two binary strings of equal length, Hamming distance is the     number of bit positions in which the two bits are different.

**Hamming distance with xor and sum**

> a = [1, 1, 0, 0];
>
> b = [1, 0, 1, 0];
>
> diff = xor(a,b)
>
> d = sum(diff)

answer will be :

> d = 2

Answer (score 0):

In matlab we can do it like this:

```
function dist = ham_dist(a,b,min_length)
%hamming distance of a, b. a and b are strings of decimal numbers respectively.
a = a*1-48;
b = b*1-48;
dist = sum(bitxor(a,b),2);
end
```

basically it is used a*1-48 is converting a binary string to row vector so that we can use bitxor. bitxor gives 1 at the positions they (a,b) differ, and 0 elsewhere.
taking sum of those gives hamming distance which is the count of no. of places where two binary numbers differ.